# Airflow Variable masked

Tags: airflow

When using a Variable named xxxx_apiKey in airflow it masks the value of the variable in the UI as expected. But when we are trying to use that variable in a DAG the value returned from:
`Variable.get('xxxx_apiKey')`
returns the masked value ******.

Is there a method parameter to retrieve the value unmasked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're calling should decrypt your secret when calling it. In my opinion, you've rewritten by mistake the variable and the real content now contains stars. This may happen through the web interface. Try storing again the content of this variable and see if it works now.

Comment: Fairly certain we did not write in straight asterisks. But will definitely give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion. Will come back and mark it correct if it works.

Comment: Not sure if that worked. Forgot to come back straight away. Going to make it correct anyway.